# How to format label in Xamarin XAML Listview based on a viewmodel attribute

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I am trying to create a ListView cell data template with a label that shows either a "detailed" description or a "short" description based on whether another variable ViewLevel is "Detailed" or "Short".

I am using an IValueConverter and trying to bind the ConverterParameter, but that does not work as I don't think the ConverterParameter is bindable.

Is there a best practice for doing this?

The label I currently have is:

```
<Label Binding Options, Converter={viewModels:DetailLabelConverter}, ConverterParameter='Detail'}" />
```

It works, but obviously has the hardcoded Detail view.  I've also tried:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Options, Converter={viewModels:DetailLabelConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={x:Reference BasePage}, Path=BindingContext.ViewLevel}}"/>
```

Which works, insomuch as it calls the DetailLabelConverter.  Unfortunately the parameter is not loaded with the value of ViewLevel but a Xamarin.Forms.Binding object.

It seems like this should be a fairly common pattern but I can't find a reasonable solution.

Comment: Try setting the `ConverterParameter` to `.`. which means it will provide you with the bound object.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, I tried to set the ConverterParameter binding to . but the result is still a Xamarin.Forms.Binding object coming into parameter rather than the actual object.

Comment: As a workaround you could consider using DataTrigger for the ViewLevel and passing different parameter for the converter that way.